# EJB deployment in TomEE

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0

I have implemented stateless EJB for all the SOAP request and response we post to backend system. The stateless EJB is invoked using the usebean tag in JSP.

Now the aim behind this is the same interface call can be made from different JSP file on differnt application and I could just refer the same stateless EJB.

I am using Ecliper Juno to develop the EJB

Now my confusion is where to deploy the EJB code in TomEE . Could you please advise on the steps to deploy this manually ? We will automate it with Maven or Ant scripts later.

Thanks
Senthil

Answer (score 1):

I could see 2 ways to place code in TomEE.

A. You can drop your EAR in app folder. It does not exist by default, but needs to be created.

Below link should give an idea about overall directory structure.

http://openejb.apache.org/tomee-directory-structure.html

So you should put your code like below

- /apps/{your ear name} folder

  - lib (contains all the jars necessary for application like log4j, open source libraries)
  - META-INF folder
  - ejb jar
  - war for web components

B. Bundle servlets, JSPs and EJBs in same WAR. This can be deployed in tomee/webapps. This can be using Eclipse as well.
http://openejb.apache.org/deploying-in-tomee.html